# Simple project - make a 3D box tumble and fall to the ground

Tags: 3d, physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources to learn programming rigid body simulation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6351/resources-to-learn-programming-rigid-body-simulation)

Hi guys,

I want to try learning rigid-body dynamic simulation. I have done a fluid and cloth simulation before, but never anything rigid. My maths knowledge is limited in that I don't know the notation that well.

Are there any good cliff-notes, tutorials, guides on how I would accomplish a simple task like this? I don't want a super complex pdf that's only a little relevant.

Thanks.

Comment: Erin Catto's (of box2d fame) GDC slides may be relevant: http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/list

Comment: @Jari, I'd suggest putting that info in the linked dupe parent question.